# How to ensure the header floats with horizontal page expansion?

Tags: html, css, margin, floating-accuracy

How can get the

> ## News

to expand horizontal with the page instead of staying left?

```css
<!doctype html> <html> <head> <title>Technology - BBC News</title> <style type="text/css"> #topbar {
  width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#logo {
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.topbar-section {
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
  height: 100%;
}
#signin-image {
  width: 25px;
  margin: 11px 15px;
  float: left;
}
#signin-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: relative;
  top: 14px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
#wigglyline {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
}
#bell {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 9px 8px 0 8px;
}
#bell-div {
  float: left;
}
.topbar-menu {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 13px 15px 0 15px;
  height: 27px;
}
#more-arrow {
  width: 16px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#searchbox {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border;
  none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: -4px 0 5px;
  float: left;
}
#magnifying-glass {
  height: 27px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
#menu-bar-container {
  background-color: #9e2c25;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#menubar {
  width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify
}
</style> </head>
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="topbar">

    <img id="logo" src="C:\Users\Kaitlyn\Desktop\Complete Web Developer Course\images\bbc-logo.png"></img>

    <div id="signin-div" class="topbar-section">

      <img id="signin-image" src="C:\Users\Kaitlyn\Desktop\Complete Web Developer Course\images\signinimage.png"></img>

      <span id="signin-text">Sign in</span>

    </div>

    <div id="bell-div">

      <img id="wigglyline" src="C:\Users\Kaitlyn\Desktop\Complete Web Developer Course\images\squiggle.png">

      <img id="bell" src="C:\Users\Kaitlyn\Desktop\Complete Web Developer Course\images\bell.png">

    </div>

    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

      News

    </div>

    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

      Sports

    </div>

    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

      Weather

    </div>

    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

      iPlayer

    </div>

    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

      TV

    </div>


    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

      More

      <img id="more-arrow" src="C:\Users\Kaitlyn\Desktop\Complete Web Developer Course\images\downarrow.png">

    </div>

    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

      <input id="searchbox" type="text" value="Search">

      <input type="image" id="magnifying-glass" src="C:\Users\Kaitlyn\Desktop\Complete Web Developer Course\images\magnifying-glass.png">

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div id="menu-bar-container">


    <div id="menu-bar">

      <h1>News</h1>


    </div>





  </div>









</body>

</html>
```

I have attached and updated the search bar that is above the div that contains the red background and news header. While expanding the browser page horizontally you should be able to see how the search bar reacts and continues to flow with the page while the News header stays put on the left side of the page.

If I need to close a `div` differently or alter positioning please let me know.

essentially I am trying to get the website to operate like this : please follow the link http://www.completewebdevelopercourse.com/content/2-css/bbc.html

Comment: you want it to be in the center of the page?

Comment: Do you want NEWS to align center?

Comment: With in the page I am working on, there is a search bar that contains tabs that expand horizontally when the page is widened directly above the red bar with the News header. The issue I am having is trying to get the "news" to expand horizontally with in the red div, however the "news" stays stuck on the left border while the search bar above the "news" expands when the page is being widened. @NiyokoYuliawan

Comment: Can you post those codes with the search bar so that someone can see the behaviour of the search bar and try to replicate such behaviour with the news div

Comment: I have attached and updated the search bar that is above the div that contains the red background and news header. While expanding the browser page horizontally you should be able to see how the search bar reacts and continues to flow with the page while the News header stays put on the left side of the page. @repzero

Comment: check this fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/Lnkp336e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot a dash (`-`) in your css. It should `#menu-bar` instead of `#menubar`.

```css
#topbar {
  width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#logo {
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.topbar-section {
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
  height: 100%;
}
#signin-image {
  width: 25px;
  margin: 11px 15px;
  float: left;
}
#signin-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: relative;
  top: 14px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
#wigglyline {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
}
#bell {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 9px 8px 0 8px;
}
#bell-div {
  float: left;
}
.topbar-menu {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 13px 15px 0 15px;
  height: 27px;
}
#more-arrow {
  width: 16px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#searchbox {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border;
  none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: -4px 0 5px;
  float: left;
}
#magnifying-glass {
  height: 27px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
#menu-bar-container {
  background-color: #9e2c25;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-bar {  /* Change this line! */
  width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">

  <img id="logo" src="http://www.completewebdevelopercourse.com/content/2-css/images/bbc-logo.png">

  <div id="signin-div" class="topbar-section">

    <img id="signin-image" src="http://www.completewebdevelopercourse.com/content/2-css/images/signinimage.png">
    <span id="signin-text">Sign in</span>
  </div>
  <div id="bell-div">
    <img id="wigglyline" src="http://www.completewebdevelopercourse.com/content/2-css/images/wigglyline.png">
    <img id="bell" src="http://www.completewebdevelopercourse.com/content/2-css/images/bell.png">
  </div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

    News

  </div>

  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

    Sports

  </div>

  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

    Weather

  </div>

  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

    iPlayer

  </div>

  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

    TV

  </div>


  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

    More

    <img id="more-arrow" src="C:\Users\Kaitlyn\Desktop\Complete Web Developer Course\images\downarrow.png">

  </div>

  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">

    <input id="searchbox" type="text" value="Search">

    <input type="image" id="magnifying-glass" src="C:\Users\Kaitlyn\Desktop\Complete Web Developer Course\images\magnifying-glass.png">

  </div>
</div>


<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="menu-bar-container">


  <div id="menu-bar">

    <h1>News</h1>


  </div>





</div>
```

Comment: I have added more code to the origional question, which might make more sense.   
I have attached and updated the search bar that is above the div that contains the red background and news header. While expanding the browser page horizontally you should be able to see how the search bar reacts and continues to flow with the page while the News header stays put on the left side of the page.

Comment: @Siemens Your code sample doesn't have red background as you described. Please use code-snippet feature to ensure that you copied the right code.

Comment: the portion of the page I am trying to recreate is at this link -  http://www.completewebdevelopercourse.com/content/2-css/bbc.html however I can not seem to discover why the "News" text will not flow right when the browser page is expanded. @Niyoko Yuliawan

Comment: @Siemens See my edit. You just forgot to put a dash in `#menubar`,

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the time you have taken to help me.